# Which one of these approaches would yield the fastest runtime?

Tags: c#, performance, delegates, function-pointers

I am in the midst of a short thought experiment and would love some assistance.

Consider a class that calculates some output according to a function that itself can be changed, but can only be changed according to a predetermined set.

Or, some list of functions:

```
double function1(double input){
    //perform some operations
    return output;
}

double function2(double input){
    //perform some operations
    return output;
}

double function3(double input){
    //perform some operations
    return output;
}

double function4... etc.
```

Now imagine that these functions are contained within some class that predetermined which function to use whenever the class is called to calculate on some value

```
Class Calculate{

    int whichFunction = 2;

    double calculate (double input){

    //decide which function to use
    switch(whichFunction){
        case 1:
            return function1(input);
            break;
        case 2:
            return function2(input);
            break;
        case 3:
            return function3(input);
            break;
        case 4... etc..
    }

    ... predetermined functions here....
}
```

Of course the first idea in performing this is to just switch on the value and move on. But what if we instead of using a switch, simply changed the function to run?

i.e.

```
Class Calculate{

    Func<double> whichFunction;

    double calculate (double input){
        return whichFunction.Invoke(input);
    }

    void setFunction(int functionNumber){
        switch(whichFunction){
        case 1:
            whichFunction = function1;
        case 2:
            whichFunction = function2;
        case 3:
            whichFunction = function3;
        case 4... etc..
    }

    ... predetermined functions here....
}
```

Considering that which function you choose would change infrequently, or possibly even only be set once in the constructor, would avoiding the switch actually deliver a run time speed benefit or is the very act of invoking a function in this way negating the benefit.

Other possible alternatives:

1. Cascading if-else.... NO, likely the slowest approach.
2. Instead of using the Func<> generic, use a delegate.
3. Take advantage of events and simply reassign which function is assigned to the event.
4. Instead of using the Func<>, use a method pointer.

Any thoughts would be well appreciated!

Comment: If you actually care, measure. And be sure to account for JIT warmup. Even better yet, forget it - there are likely a hundred lower-hanging fruit.

Comment: Why are you doing a *thought experiment* about something that could be answered by a *real experiment*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *extremely* unlikely that the decision here will impact performance in any meaningful way.  I would imagine that the function being performed is more likely to take more time than the logic for firing it in most cases.

Each of the code snippits you've mentioned will run extremely quickly, and even if one is quicker than another, it will not be by any significant margin.  Pick whichever method is easiest for you to understand and maintain and then start looking elsewhere for performance gains *if you find that your application is performing too slowly*.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make a recommendation without knowing the bigger picture.  You might be constructing a calculator for instance and if so may wish to overload actual math operators for your functions.

If you're going with a few functions and only one of them may apply, then perhaps a layered

- `if () {} else if () {} else if () {}`

... structure may serve you better (more popular interrogations up front) as the structure would exit excution the moment your condition was met.

And of course there is the short-circuit logic for && and || functions to consider.  That short-circuit can save you loads of time depending what you're after.

Comment: the `break` in case statements serves the purpose of short-circuiting

Answer (score 0):

The "right" answer is to actually measure & compare your options.  The "pragmatic" answer is that unless you have a very large number of functions, it won't matter enough to be worth the time you've already spent thinking about this.  The "logical" answer is that your second option does switch far less frequently so it should be faster though it is not thread-safe and is an awkward API that will lead to bugs down the road (callers either forgetting to set the function or setting it so often that it defeats the purpose)

Answer (score 0):

**POITROAE.**

Use a profiler!

There are too many optimizations that are available to modern compilers to predict what will run the fastest in **your** situation. In general,

- a function call is a series of ops on the stack and a jump to a location.
- Some compilers jump for each case of a switch statement
- Some make a jump table, which can be a blessing and a curse.
- if you have variables in a scope local to the switch a stack frame may be set up.
- etc etc etc...  The `cases` are almost infinite.

That said, a switch statement with just a few lines of code in each case is likely faster than a function call.

Also, on X86, jumps and function calls can clear the caches and pipelines so you pay a good penalty for that too.

A profiler really is best for modern software.

Answer (score 0):

The relative performance for your two examples will depend on the specific context:

1. In most cases, especially if `calculate` is called a lot of times, the multiple comparisons in the switch statement will result in many branches that will get executed many times, and potentially incorrectly predicted by the CPU. This would easily outweigh the cost of the function call in the Invoke version.
2. If function1..3 are short and could be inlined, then there could be a situation where the compiler could optimize the "switch" version to be slightly faster than the "Invoke" one, since there is no way to optimize away the functions in the latter.

My advice would be to use the "Invoke" version, as in most cases it will result in optimal performance.